# Help with proving a fact about injective modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, injective-module

Let $R$ be a ring with identity.  I am trying to show that an $R$-module $A$ is
injective if and and only if for every left ideal $L$ of $R$ and every
$R$-module homomorphism $g: L \rightarrow A$, there exists an
$a \in A$ such that $g(r) = ra$ for all $r \in L$.

I can show that $A$ is injective given that $g(r) = ra$ for all
$r \in L$ by extending $g$ to an $R$-module homomorphism
$h: R \rightarrow A$, but I am having trouble showing the other
direction. Any hints as to why there exists an $a \in A$ such that
$g(r) = ra$ for all $r \in L$ given that $A$ is injective?

Comment: Doesn't it follow from the definition of injective, unless you have a different definition of injective. One definition says, given an injective map $i:X\to Y$ of $R$-modules and a homomorphism $f:X\to A$, there exists a homomorphism $g:Y\to A$ such that $g\circ i=f$. So, in your situation, you get a map $R\to A$ extending $g$. But any map $F:R\to A$ is just given by multiplication by $a=F(1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\tilde g\colon R\longrightarrow A$ be an extension of $ g\colon L\longrightarrow A$ to $R$ and  let $r\in L$. We have
$$g(r)=\tilde g(r) = \tilde g(r\cdot 1)=r\tilde g(1),$$
so just set $a=\tilde g(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Say $L \overset\iota\hookrightarrow R$ is the natural inclusion. Injectivity of $A$ implies for any $g: L \to A$ there is a $G: R \to A$ such that $G\circ \iota = g$. Take $a = G(1_R)$; then for any $r \in L$, we have that $g(r) = (G\circ \iota)(r) = G(r) = rG(1_R) = ra$.